# Glitchy DOM rendering ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router, create-react-app

[image]

If you look closely to the GIF above you can see that when I refresh the page it loads the components and styling of my ReactJS app one by one. This problem occurs in the local development environment as well on live production build. I'm using the **react-create-app** build and run scripts. I also use **react-router** for redirecting.

What can cause this phased loading?

Comment: I could only guess but it looks like you have your cache disabled in the browser and are loading CSS styles from a CDN (bootstrap?) which doesn't get cached for some reason so every time you hit refresh it gets redownloaded and reapplied. Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: I've tried using other browsers and it works fine. In the GIF's case i'm using Chrome but it looks like the complete css isn't getting cached. Even after I disabled the CDN's the problem is still there.

Comment: Have you perhaps disabled your cache in chrome dev tools? https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache

Comment: No, the box is unchecked.